How is nominal width of condoms related to penis girth?
What is the mathematical relation between the girth of the penis (defined as the maximum circumference) and the nominal width of the condom (an industry label) that should be used? I see a lot of contradicting information on the internet. My question is about latex condoms. All sources below are either about latex condoms or condoms in general.
On the one hand, Healthline and Very Well Health say that you should divide the girth by 3.14 to get the width.

You can figure out the width of your penis the same way you’d determine the diameter of a circle. To do this, divide your girth measurement by 3.14. The resulting number is your width.


To calculate the width, divide the girth by 3.14. For example, if your penis girth is 5 inches, then the penis width would be 1.59 inches (5 inches ÷ 3.14 = 1.59 inches).

On the other hand, many webites provide tables in which the ratio is between 2 and 2.5: condom-sizes, condomerie, postcondooms. Consider this quote from condomerie.com:

Regular sized condoms usually range from around 52 – 54mm, meaning they’ll fit those with a girth of around 110 – 120mm.

The ratio is here around 115/53=2.2; this is much smaller than 3.14. There is also a Reddit post with 565 upvotes, stating that nominal width should be 2.36 times smaller than penis girth:

How do you compute the "nominal width" that you require? There's a simple calculation that most people aren't taught. You measure your wrap-around circumference and divide by 2.36.

So what is the correct method, dividing by 3.14, or dividing by something like 2.36?

Are you referring to latex, polyisoprene, polyurethane or even animal skin or intestines (or bladder) condoms? Different materials naturally have different stretchiness.

It's about latex condoms. I will edit my question to reflect this

3.14 isn't some random number, it's an approximation for pi and is the literal conversion between diameter and circumference. My understanding is that 1) different manufacturers measure their sizing differently, 2) latex condoms are stretchy, one size is meant to accommodate a broad range of anatomy, and 3) in the literature, the focus is on reliable use which means finding a comfortable size that doesn't slip. There's little emphasis made on anything but personal preference because the perceived most important variable in protection is consistent use.

Additionally, penises are not cylindrical, and you're not going to be able to summarize "fit" in one number. I think it probably does not make sense to approach this question with the quantitative specificity you're looking for, it's more sensible to consider fit from the perception of each individual.

@Bryan Krause, although pi is the ratio between the diameter and circumference of a circle, this does not mean that it is the ratio between condom width and circumference. When you flatten out a condom, the ratio could be 2 instead of 3.14. According to condom-sizes.org: 'To calculate its circumference we would have to multiply that number with 2, for example, a condom with a 2.05 inch flat width would have a circumference of around 4.1 inches.' https://www.condom-sizes.org/condom-sizes/condom-sizes#ref

@BryanKrause, all the websites I mentioned provide instructions for measuring condom size in great detail. Dividing by 3.14 or 2.3 makes a huge difference. For example, consider a penis girth of 5 inches. Dividing by 3.14 gives a width of 1.6 inches; indicating one should buy a small condom. Om the other hand, dividing by 2.3 gives a width of 2.2 inches; indicating one should buy a large condom.

@Riemann Like I also said, there's no standard for how condom manufacturers measure their size. Diameter is one possible measurement. Flat width is another possible measurement. They need not be the same size for the entire length. You're trying to summarize a multidimensional problem into one number. This is an impossible task. Anyone can take a fairly complex problem and create simplified instructions to solve it, but that doesn't make one of them "right" and another "wrong" and does not mean that there is even a meaningful way to tell.

I think there's only two ways to measure this, the diameter and flat width; and it would make sense if industry labels are standardized in one way or the other. What I'm looking for is a reliable source that settles the issue.

The actual way that is suggested in literature and by the manufacturers is to go based on fit, not equations. Condoms are inexpensive and disposable. Rather than use a formula that may not work for everyone, it would be better to try a size and go from there based on fit, possibly trying different manufacturers if one manufacturer doesn't have a suitable fit.

What if the width is not constant along the length? Still only two ways to measure? Does temperature matter? Do you measure ID or OD? How flat is "flat" when something cannot actually be laid perfectly flat? Would the rule for the best choice not also depend on the stretchiness/thickness/thinness? Also, as far as standards: https://xkcd.com/927/

On the websites I linked in my question, it is suggested to measure the width at the point of largest circumference.

What if that doesn't match with your experience of what is a good fit and what isn't?

Maybe its then best to focus on the following question: do condom manufacturers define width as flat width (half the circumference) of diameter (circumference divided by pi)? The reason that some websites mention factors slightly larger than 2 is that there should be some radial force (stretching) on the condom; I saw somewhere that penis circumference should be 10-20 % larger than condom width.

On condom-sizes.org, they refer to two articles to support this claim. https://www.condom-sizes.org/condom-sizes/condom-calculator#work

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The root of this confusion is the relation between penis circumference and condom width. Intuitively, it seems logical that the condom width equals the diameter of the penis, which is 3.14 (pi) times smaller than the circumference. However, this is not how the condom industry defines condom width. The number that you can see on condom packages is the nominal width. This is called the `flat width' by the International Organization for Standardization. On page 5 of the ISO standard it says (I made the part bold):

For the purpose of this test, the mid-body width is the mean flat width rounded to the nearest 0,5 mm of
13 condoms measured in accordance with Annex E at a point (75 ± 5) mm from the closed end excluding
the reservoir tip.

When a condom is laid flat, its width equals half its circumference. The only source cited by the Healthline article that talks about condom width, is condom-sizes.org. This website has a page where they explain the difference between flat width and diameter:

Flat width = Circumference/2


Flat width ≈ 1.57*diameter

We have now arrived at a factor 2. The reason for using a slightly larger factor, is that condom circumference should be smaller than penis circumference. This makes sure the condom is tight enough. According to condom-sizes-org, this ratio should be as follows:

A study that examined the effect of penis dimensions on the likelihood of condom breakage or slippage discovered that the ideal ratio between condom circumference and penis circumference should be from 80 to 90%.

Combining the numbers, the factor between penis circumference and nominal width should be between 2.2 and 2.4.
